# How to resolve a spanning tree issue on a server trunk port?

Tags: cisco, switch, spanning-tree, cisco-nexus, hsrp

I am having a very strange `spanning-tree` issue with Cisco Nexus switches.

My server is connected to the `TOR` switch with trunk configuration because we have multiple VLANs on the server. When I reboot the server it creates chaos in spanning tree; and, because of that, my network freezes live traffic for few seconds until spanning-tree get settled down. This is very odd.

[image]

`SW1` & `SW2` are configured in `vPC` and I have configured `VLAN 100` in HSRP configuration. I am having this issue with only the VLAN 100 traffic.

`SW1` & `SW2` spanning tree configuration:

```
spanning-tree loopguard default
spanning-tree vlan 10,20,30,40,100 priority 8192
```

Spanning tree details:

```
sw1# sh spanning-tree vlan 100

VLAN0100
  Spanning tree enabled protocol rstp
  Root ID    Priority    8292
             Address     0023.04ee.be01
             This bridge is the root
             Hello Time  2  sec  Max Age 20 sec  Forward Delay 15 sec

  Bridge ID  Priority    8292   (priority 8192 sys-id-ext 100)
             Address     0023.04ee.be01
             Hello Time  2  sec  Max Age 20 sec  Forward Delay 15 sec
```

HSRP configuration:

```
interface Vlan100
  description *** VLAN 100 ***
  no shutdown
  mtu 9216
  no autostate
  no ip redirects
  ip address 74.200.100.2/23
  no ip ospf passive-interface
  ip router ospf 100 area 0.0.0.0
  hsrp 1
    preempt
    priority 110
    ip 74.200.100.1
```

On TOR switch port e1/27 connected to the server:

```
interface Ethernet1/27
  description Connected to server 
  switchport mode trunk
  switchport trunk allowed vlan 10,20,30,100
  spanning-tree port type edge
  spanning-tree bpduguard enable
```

The issue occurs every single time I physically reboot the server. It causes my `spanning-tree` topology to change which disturbs vlan 100 traffic and I see lots of packet drops.

You can see here on TOR switch, port `e1/27` just changed topology:

```
swt-tor# show spanning-tree detail | inc ieee|occurr|from
  Number of topology changes 69 last change occurred 0:13:50 ago
          from Ethernet1/27
  Number of topology changes 69 last change occurred 0:13:50 ago
          from Ethernet1/27
  Number of topology changes 69 last change occurred 0:13:50 ago
          from Ethernet1/27
  Number of topology changes 5 last change occurred 69:38:03 ago
          from port-channel36
  Number of topology changes 69 last change occurred 0:13:50 ago
          from Ethernet1/27
```

- How do I tell spanning tree to not change spanning tree on the connected server trunk port?
- How this is impacting only VLAN 100 (HSRP interface)?

Comment: Crap!!! never mind this solved my problem `spanning-tree port type edge trunk` look like

Comment: Please post your answer and accept it so we'll all see that this question is resolved.

Comment: @JeffLearman done! but i have to wait for 2 days to accept my own answer ;)

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Solved

This command was missing in `e1/27` interface.

`spanning-tree port type edge trunk`

Full interface output look like following.

```
interface Ethernet1/27
  description Connected to server 
  switchport mode trunk
  switchport trunk allowed vlan 10,20,30,100
  spanning-tree port type edge trunk
  spanning-tree bpduguard enable
```